# Can we read grade values from grade categories through Valence?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

We would like to read the calculated value of a specific Grade Category, as opposed to its configuration, through Valence.

According to the docs [here](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html), we can retrieve grade values through this endpoint:

> > **GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/grades/(gradeObjectId)/values/(userId)** 
> >     Retrieve a specific grade value for a particular user assigned in an org unit.

Is it possible to use the above API on a Grade Category to get its value instead of a Grade Item?

Just to be clear, we would like to get the value for the category in one single shot without having to look into what grade items are inside the category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API doesn't currently expose the calculated value for a category in a single route. You'll have to get the category, and using the array of GradeObjects that comes back, grab the corresponding grade values, and then use the properties of the category to calculate the mark.